# Swift 4 - expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time

Tags: swift, compiler-errors

Turning to Swift 4, gives an error "Expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time; consider breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions"

```
let value =
  Int(topLeft.hashValue) |
  Int(topRight.hashValue) << 1 |
  Int(bottomLeft.hashValue) << 2 |
  Int(bottomRight.hashValue) << 3
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfKg2.png)

Comment: Do it piece by piece? `let value = Int(topLeft.hashValue); value = value | Int(topRight.hashValue) << 1;` etc.?

Comment: `hashValue` is already an `Int` You don't need the `Int(...)` conversions

Comment: Thanks for the help, everything now works as it should

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var value = topLeft.hashValue
    value = value | topRight.hashValue << 1
    value = value | bottomLeft.hashValue << 2
    value = value | bottomRight.hashValue << 3
```

Comment: You can also use the in-place `|=` operator, e.g `value |= topRight.hashValue << 1`